# How to select the first record from multiple records

Tags: soql

I'm looking for some assistance in a simple SOQL statement. I haven't written SQL for over 15 years (so a real newbie to SOQL)

Looking for what i believe must be a simple SOQL statement. I used SQL many years ago but now have an urgent need to get my data volumes down, fast.

I have multiple records in a table and I only want to select the latest record for each client.

I was thinking it would be easy using the sorted data (by date record added) and then using the First function. But it lt appears the First function is very different from SQL to SOQL

for example the data looks like this:

- Cln_Id,          Client_name,          dte_attach_added
- 00001            Mary Blogs           13/01/2014
- 00001            Mary Blogs           29/02/2013
- 00001            Mary Blogs           15/03/2015
- 00341            Billy Bobs           07/11/2014
- 00789            Wendy Woo            09/10/2014
- 00789            Wendy Woo            15/11/2014

I am looking to select the client record with the latest attachment date.

any assistance is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you please let us know what is the data type of latest attachment date either date or datetime?

If this is datetime then we can use group by SOQL:
List<AggregateResult> lstA = [select ClnId, ClnName, MAX(attachdate) from ObjectName group by clnId, clnName];

Answer (score 9):

you can use **ORDER BY** in your SOQL to first sort the records by attachment date in descending order (so that you get latest -> oldest) and 
then use **LIMIT** to get only the top 1 record which is the latest..

```
Select Id, Name from YourObject Order By AttachmentDateField__c Desc Limit 1
```

in the above SOQL, replace YourObject with your actual object name and AttachmentDateField__c with your actual attachment date field name and include any additional fields you want to retrieve.